# Deepmind Spriteworld run_demo.py not found

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deepmind

I'm trying to run the Deepmind Spriteworld demo described on the [project's GitHub page](https://github.com/deepmind/spriteworld), but I'm not finding `run_demo.py` in the distribution and the closest sounding file, `demo_ui.py` doesn't launch a UI  when run (tried both on Linux and Windows).

How should the Deepmind Spriteworld demo UI be launched?

Comment: I cannot get it to run either, even when cloning and installing direct from the repo (when `run_demo.py` is available)

Answer (score 0):

I posted the question to the [project's issue page](https://github.com/deepmind/spriteworld/issues/1), where the recommendation was to manually download and run [run_demo.py](https://github.com/deepmind/spriteworld/blob/master/run_demo.py). That worked for me.